# Why pixel values inverted and transposed on loading image in Python?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am trying to access the pixels of a grayscale image. On loading it, I found that the pixel values are transposed as well as the color of the new image 'img.png' is inverted. But ideally, 'img.png' should be same as 'cat.png'. Why are they different?

> ```
> import numpy as np
> from PIL import Image
>
> img=Image.open('cat.png')
> pix=img.load()
> res_list=[]
> img_data= np.zeros((128, 128), dtype=np.uint8)
> for i in range(img.size[0]):
>   for j in range(img.size[1]):
>       img_data[i,j]=pix[i,j]
>
> img=Image.fromarray(img_data)
> img.save('img.png')
> ```

Also, when I tried to update img_data as:

> ```
> img_data[i,j]=255-pix[i,j]
> ```

still it wasn't the actual image, but very white image. How can I recover the original image?

The images are:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'transposed' and 'inverted' exactly? Give an example.

Comment: @barny you can run the code on any gray scale image to see. 'img.png' is black where 'cat.png' is white and vice versa. Also, 'img.png' is transposed form of 'cat.png'

Comment: I ran your code on a greyscale image and the colors look just fine. Please use imgur or a similar hosting service to show the exact input image you're using and the exact output image you're getting.

Comment: Does `Image.fromarray(img_data, mode='L')` produce anything different?

Comment: @JeD no it didn't produce any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with gelezko's suggestion to switch indexing order. This will solve the transposition problem.

The color problem appears to occur because the input image isn't actually greyscale. When I tried `print img.mode`, I got "P" rather than "L". Try explicitly converting to L before doing any work on the pixels.

```
img=Image.open('cat.png')
img = img.convert("L")
pix=img.load()
```

Now you should get a properly oriented & colored image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

**Right code:**

```
img_data[j,i]=pix[i,j]
```

Just swap `i` and `j` in `img_data`.

Comment: This will fix the transposition effect, but I'm still curious why OP is seeing inverted colors... Could it be an endianness issue?

Comment: Like @Kevin said, it doesn't help me in inverted colors

Comment: I do not know. I check this example for RGB image and everything is ok. Try to use OpenCV =)